# Reuse same layer of Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I hope to wrap up `ConvolutionLayer` in a way so that it takes two inputs, does the same operation on those, and outputs their result respectively. For example, `MyConv[a,b]` should have two output port for a and b. It is easy to use in pytorch - by simply calling that layer twice, but I can't  see how to do it in mathematica. Any help is welcome

Comment: `NetMapThreadOperator` sounds like what you are looking for...perhaps with a `CatenateLayer` to turn your two separate input ports into a single pair input and a `PartLayer` to split them up on output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A neat way to use layers with the same parameters in multiple places is with shared arrays (via `NetInsertSharedArrays`). These are parameters that are shared among multiple instances of the same layer. E.g.

```
conv = NetInsertSharedArrays@ConvolutionLayer[10, 3];

net = NetInitialize@NetGraph[
    {conv, conv},
    {NetPort["a"] -> 1, NetPort["b"] -> 2},
    "a" -> {5, 10, 10}, "b" -> {5, 20, 20}];
```

Now the two instances of `conv` are not independent as they would normally be and if you train the net and extract the convolution weights you can see they are identical

```
net2 = NetTrain[net, "RandomData", MaxTrainingRounds -> 10];

NetExtract[net2, {1, "Weights"}] == NetExtract[net2, {2, "Weights"}]

(* True *)
```